# Run a query based on a condition

Tags: plsql

I am trying to run a query based on the day

For example

- if it is the first of the month then select * from thistable
- if it is the 2nd of the month then select * from thattable

Etc

What would be the best way to do this?

Apologize in advance if this is vague, new to PL/SQL. I know how to do it in tsql.

I've tried below

```
DECLARE 
DATENUM INT := 1;

begin
 if DATENUM = 1 
        then 
             select * from thistable;
        else 
            select '* from thattable;

end if;

end;
```

Comment: Different databases?  You need to create a link in oracle.

Comment: read up on dynamic sql in oracle with "execute immediate" using a cursor.

Comment: Do the tables have the same columns with the same data types?  And what do you want to do with the data - PL/SQL cannot only SELECT data, it has to go somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE
  v NUMBER;
BEGIN
  v:=To_number(To_char(SYSDATE,'dd')) ;
  IF v=1 THEN
    --statement_1-----
  ELSIF v=2 THEN
    NULL;
    --statement_2-----
  END IF;
END;
```

Note : In PL/SQL INTO clause should be there in select.